# how to upload .txt files to sql database using asp.net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, text-files

how to upload .txt files to sql database using asp.net(C#)

Comment: Do you really need to store the file in the database, or just the contents? If just the contents then just read it and store the text in a Varchar(MAX) column.

Comment: Could you be more specific?
txt files with sql's in side, witch must be executed, or txt files with some random text inside for storing info only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something that will be done manually by a user?

If so, how about an [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) application?

In your [View](http://www.asp.net/Learn/MVC/tutorial-04-cs.aspx):

```
<h2>
    Upload A File of Foos</h2>
<%
    Html.BeginForm("LoadFoos", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" });
%>
<label for="foosFile">
    Foos file:
</label>
<input type="file" name="FileUpload1" id="foosFile" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
<%
    Html.EndForm();
%>
```

In your [Controller](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-03-cs.aspx):

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LoadFoos()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            // This illustrates how to read the uploaded file contents,
            // and would need to be adapted to your scenario
            List<string> foos = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    foos.Add(line);
                }
            }

            // TODO: use LINQ 2 SQL, NHibernate or ADO.NET to load the foos directly,
            // or call a web/WCF service behind your firewall that does this
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```